# Difference between provider-hosted app and SharePoint-hosted app + IFRAME for provider

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, provider-hosted-app

Assume I have an external web application that I want to use as provider for a provider-hosted app.

What is the difference between the following two approaches:

1. Using a *provider-hosted app* and point it to the web application as provider
2. Using a *SharePoint-hosted app*, add an `IFRAME` and point the `IFRAME` to the web application

Some minor differences I see:

- The SharePoint-hosted app needs to get and pass the `{StandardTokens}` "manually"
- The SharePoint-hosted app can dynamically alter the provider URL, the provider-hosted app has to use a fixed one

But apart from that - are there any implications I need to be aware of when (say) using approach 2 instead of 1?

Authentication?

Authorization?

Convenience functions missing with the second approach?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would rather my app be in a single place. Your scenario #2 has pages in the App and pages in the external site.

Also, a primary consideration is what functionality you will be delivering in your app. If you don't need to consume any SharePoint resources, you could simply use a Page Viewer Web Part to show your external site in a page.

Comment: You have valid points here which concern the overall architecture. But there might be restrictions/implications forcing us to chose one of the proposed architectures. I'm interpreting your answer as: "I don't see any of those." (Right?)